# Not sure what this is exactly called but, page.php?id=5

Tags: php, mysql

So basically my site is using a mysql db and the id is auto incremented.
So in my db there's

```
1 Kevin
2 Nick
3 Jon
```

I want to make it so if a person wants to look at Kevin's profile, the link to it is

```
 site.com/profile.php?id=1
```

That link would pull up Kevin's profile

Comment: Can you post the code that you already tried? You are also looking at using the `GET` superglobal.

Comment: As already stated, using a GET is to be used, plus you could make use of a [`WHERE`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm) clause, in conjunction with that; which is one way of achieving this. I.e.: `WHERE user='$id'`. Be sure to use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept you're searching for is called "routing", which is how a URL gets routed to particular content. This concept can be extremely complex (e.g. using a 3rd party routing framework like symfony), or as simple as checking:

```
$userId = $_GET['id'];
/* some mysqli/pdo/etc. code to grab info on that user */
```

Comment: It's also super ugly from a user perspective, exposing way too much information about what's going on. Most [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) have some way of cleaning this up and present it like `/profile/1` to avoid clutter.